# Mid() don't extract string in accurate position

Tags: vba

I am using VBA in Ms Access environment, to handle long string (memo field storing HTML originally).
After positioning by Instr(), I put the position into Mid(vStr,vStartPos,vEndPos-vStartPos+1) to extract the string, but the output doesn't match. I have already carefully checked this in immediate windows, as well as NotePad++. What I can say is Instr() and NotePad++ have given the same counting result, while Mid() is different. Mid()'s result are former than Instr()'s in some cases, and latter in other cases. I don't know the reason, and can just believe Mid() use different mechanism or have defeative (surprised!) in handling long string mixed with single-byte and bi-byte chars (but this is common in the world, and meet no problem before), and possibly some special characters.

I believe I need to custom-make a Mid() function. Any idea how to do it effectively and efficiently?

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: I read it multiple times, I still can't make sense of *"Mid()'s result are former than Instr()'s in some cases, and latter in other cases."* - care to [edit] and rephrase a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your reply. After I created a custom Mid() by RegEx and find that the problem has no change, I have found out the silly mistake I made. The Instr() and Mid() have no problem, but the string has been carelessly modified between them. So this case should be closed now.